# ConnectEx requires the socket to be "initially bound", but to what?

Tags: windows, network-programming, winsock, overlapped-io

The [ConnectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function requires an "unconnected, previously bound socket".  Indeed, if I omit the [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) step in my example (see below), [ConnectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) fails with [WSAEINVAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681391%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#WSAEINVAL).

Here's my current understanding: before calling [ConnectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), [bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737550%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) the socket to `INADDR_ANY` and port 0 (unless it is already bound):

```
struct sockaddr_in addr;
ZeroMemory(&addr, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
addr.sin_port = 0;
rc = bind(sock, (SOCKADDR*) &addr, sizeof(addr));
if (rc != 0) { ... bind failed; call WSAGetLastError to see why ... }
```

Or for an IPv6 socket:

```
struct sockaddr_in6 addr;
ZeroMemory(&addr, sizeof(addr));
addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
addr.sin6_port = 0;
rc = bind(sock, (SOCKADDR*) &addr, sizeof(addr));
if (rc != 0) { ... bind failed; call WSAGetLastError to see why ... }
```

This lets the operating system assign a *local address* to our socket (as opposed to the *remote address* we are connecting to).  [connect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737625%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does this step automatically, but [ConnectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737606%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not.

My questions are:

1. Is my assessment correct?
2. Is there a way to do this automatic bind that is agnostic to the address family, or will I have to handle each of `AF_INET`, `AF_INET6`, `AF_BTH` (Bluetooth), etc. manually?

Working ConnectEx example (also on Gist: https://gist.github.com/4158972):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <MSWSock.h>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

struct mswsock_s {
    LPFN_CONNECTEX ConnectEx;
} mswsock;

static BOOL load_mswsock(void)
{
    SOCKET sock;
    DWORD dwBytes;
    int rc;

    /* Dummy socket needed for WSAIoctl */
    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
        return FALSE;

    {
        GUID guid = WSAID_CONNECTEX;
        rc = WSAIoctl(sock, SIO_GET_EXTENSION_FUNCTION_POINTER,
                      &guid, sizeof(guid),
                      &mswsock.ConnectEx, sizeof(mswsock.ConnectEx),
                      &dwBytes, NULL, NULL);
        if (rc != 0)
            return FALSE;
    }

    rc = closesocket(sock);
    if (rc != 0)
        return FALSE;

    return TRUE;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int rc;
    BOOL ok;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    SOCKET sock;

    rc = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
    if (rc != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", rc);
        return 1;
    }
    if (LOBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2 || HIBYTE(wsaData.wVersion) != 2) {
        printf("Your computer is from the wrong millenium.\n");
        WSACleanup();
        return 1;
    }

    if (!load_mswsock()) {
        printf("Error loading mswsock functions: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET) {
        printf("socket: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    /* ConnectEx requires the socket to be initially bound. */
    {
        struct sockaddr_in addr;
        ZeroMemory(&addr, sizeof(addr));
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
        addr.sin_port = 0;
        rc = bind(sock, (SOCKADDR*) &addr, sizeof(addr));
        if (rc != 0) {
            printf("bind failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
    }

    /* Issue ConnectEx and wait for the operation to complete. */
    {
        OVERLAPPED ol;
        ZeroMemory(&ol, sizeof(ol));

        sockaddr_in addr;
        ZeroMemory(&addr, sizeof(addr));
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("173.194.37.36"); // google.com
        addr.sin_port = htons(80);

        ok = mswsock.ConnectEx(sock, (SOCKADDR*) &addr, sizeof(addr), NULL, 0, NULL, &ol);
        if (ok) {
            printf("ConnectEx succeeded immediately\n");
        } else if (WSAGetLastError() == ERROR_IO_PENDING) {
            printf("ConnectEx pending\n");

            DWORD numBytes;
            ok = GetOverlappedResult((HANDLE) sock, &ol, &numBytes, TRUE);
            if (ok)
                printf("ConnectEx succeeded\n");
            else
                printf("ConnectEx failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        } else {
            printf("ConnectEx failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            return 1;
        }
    }

    /* Make the socket more well-behaved. */
    rc = setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_UPDATE_CONNECT_CONTEXT, NULL, 0);
    if (rc != 0) {
        printf("SO_UPDATE_CONNECT_CONTEXT failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    /* This will fail if SO_UPDATE_CONNECT_CONTEXT was not performed. */
    rc = shutdown(sock, SD_BOTH);
    if (rc != 0) {
        printf("shutdown failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Done\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

> connect does this step automatically, but ConnectEx does not.

Correct.

> Is my assessment correct?

Yes.

> Is there a way to do this automatic bind that is agnostic to the address family, or will I have to handle each of AF_INET, AF_INET6, AF_BTH (Bluetooth), etc. manually?

I believe that `INADDR_ANY` is a bunch of zeros in all address families, so you could just try using the `memset()` and omitting the assignment to `addr.sin_addr.s_addr` completely. Whether this is kosher, portable, politically correct etc. is another question into which I will not enter.

It seems pretty curious that Microsoft didn't manage to have `ConnectEx()` call `bind()` internally, considering that saving system calls is the motivation for its existence, and also considering that most programs never bind an outbound socket at all.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to get the bind address for ConnectEx in an address family independent way.

**Solution 1**

Call `getaddrinfo` with the following options:

```
pServiceName = "0"

hints.ai_flags = AI_PASSIVE
hints.ai_family = address family of the socket
```

Then use the first result of the returned address list.

To get the address family of the socket you can use `getsockopt` with `SO_PROTOCOL_INFOW`.

**Solution 2**

Use `SOCKADDR_STORAGE` for the address structure and call `INETADDR_SETANY` which is defined in `MSTcpIP.h`. It supports `AF_INET` and `AF_INET6`.